# Notation on derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation, partial-derivative

In general, there are a few ways to highlight derivative of the function, like $\frac{d}{dx}, \; f'(x), \; \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \; f'_x$ etc.

However, the question touches another context. For example, let a polynomial function $f(x)$ be explicitly defined as follows

$$f(x) = x^n, \quad x\in N, \; n\in N$$

This way it is normal to use ordinary derivative operator, since there is only 1 argument in function $f(x)$,

$$\frac{d}{dx} f(x).$$

However, assume that there is no explicit definition of function $f$, and it is necessary just to denote derivative of polynomial $x^n$ over $x$, which of above is correct way to do it:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} x^n$$

Or

$$\frac{d}{dx} x^n, \quad n = const ?$$

Or maybe another thing ?

Comment: If it's clear in the context that you stick to a single variable and that $n$ is a _constant_ parameter, then I'd choose the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite unusual that when you write $$x^n,$$ $n$ be silently a function of $x$ or other variables.

Either you should state it or write

$$x^{n(x,y)}.$$

So in normal times

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^n$$ is unambiguous and partials would be confusing, while if $n$ is not independent of $x$,

$$\frac d{dx}x^n$$ and 
$$\frac\partial{\partial x}x^n$$

denote two different things.

In fact, you don't have to say that $n$ is constant; you have to warn when it is not.